# AngularJS translate: Format dynamic dates

Tags: angularjs, date, angular-translate

Using AngularJS and angular-translate I am trying to insert a date as parameter in a translated text.

The basic task is documented by the translate package:

```
<p>{{ 'MyText' | translate:{myDate:someControllerDate} }}</p>
```

with this in a localized json-file:

```
(english)'MyText': 'This is the date: {{myDate}}.'
(danish) 'MyText': 'Dette {{myDate}} er datoen.'
```

This gives me:

*(english) This is the date: 2015-04-29T00:00:00.*

*(danish) Dette 2015-04-29T00:00:00 er datoen.*

**The problem:**
I would like to format the date to match the language (or culture, but for now the language will be good enough).

The desired result is:

*(english) This is the date: 04-29-2015.*

*(danish)  Dette 29-04-2015 er datoen.*

I was hoping for a syntax along these lines:

```
(english)'MyText': 'This is the date: {{myDate:MM-dd-yyyy}}.'
(danish) 'MyText': Dette {{myDate:dd-MM-yyyy}} er datoen.'
```

Or perhaps:

```
<p>{{ 'MyText' | translate:{{myDate:someControllerDate | translate:'MyDateFormat'}} }}</p>
```

with

```
(english)'MyDateFormat': 'MM-dd-yyyy'
(danish) 'MyDateFormat': 'dd-MM-yyyy'
```

Is there a way to achieve the desired result, preferably without having to format the date inside the controller (keeping logic and view separated)?

Comment: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Can you give an example on how it could be used with angular-translate?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you have following `angular-translate` translations definitions:

```
//de    
"with_date": "German: {{date|date:'short'}}"

//en    
"with_date": "English: {{date|date:'medium'}}"
```

Then inside a view you can do:

```
<h1>{{ 'with_date'|translate:{date:today} }}</h1>
```

Where `today` is defined in controller i.e.:

```
$scope.today = new Date();
```

Assuming you've loaded [`angular-locale_*`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n) with correct locale the dates will be formatted in a language/country specific way.

Here's a [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Zyx7Sh?p=preview).

Having said that localization mechanism built into angular ([`ngLocale`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$locale)) is very limited and when it comes to dates you can accomplish wonders with [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: from the docs: `The Angular datetime filter uses the time zone settings of the browser.`, so this will not work unless you also change the browser lang with `$translate.use('en_US')`