# AngularJS input date french

Tags: angularjs, date, date-format

I wanted to use an input[date] inside a form to enable users to use the modern browsers' support, without using a javascript datepicker.
For the ones who're using not supporting browsers, I'v set [ui-mask](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask). Both work together.
I use the french format (dd/mm/YYYY).

```
<input type="date" ng-model="myDate" ui-mask="99/99/9999">
$scope.myDate = new Date("2016-02-12"); // works
$scope.myDate = "12/02/2016"; // Doesn't...
```

In an empty form, no problem, Angular accept it.
But with a filled form, Angular expects a date format I don't want : YYYY-mm-dd (javascript date object).

I can't understand why Angular only provides support that format, and not others like french format. Because I want the input[date] to show the french format, not the standard one !

Many modern browsers provides interesting support for dates, I can't understand why Angular waste that.

Or maybe I missed something ?

Comment: you can find a solution on this stack thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937780/angularjs-translate-format-dynamic-dates

Comment: `myDate` is supposed to be a `Date` object, so `$scope.myDate = "12/02/2016"` is invalid.

Comment: You want to bind prepared value with french format from angular app to input[type=date]?

Comment: @EnverDzhaparoff Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal need to use `momentJs` and `ngModel` `$parsers` and `$formatters`. Below some code and JSFiddle example:

In your controller you prepare some string value in french date format:

```
$scope.myDate= '12/02/2016';
```

In view you set this value to ngModel attribute of `input[type=date]` element:

```
<input class="form-control" type="date" ng-model="myDate">
```

You need to create new directive, it can be assigned to `input` element:

```
.directive('input', function(dateFilter) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            if (
                'undefined' !== typeof attrs.type && 'date' === attrs.type && ngModel
            ) {
                ngModel.$formatters.push(function(modelValue) {
                    return moment(modelValue, "DD/MM/YYYY").toDate();
                });

                ngModel.$parsers.push(function(viewValue) {
                    return moment(viewValue).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
                });
            }
        }
    }
})
```

New function in `$formatters` array modifies your `myDate` to javascript date object (with moment parser it's pretty simple). New function in $parsers array modifies value of input element back to french formatted date string.

This solution provides two way binding between your `myDate` and `input[type=date]` element. :)

Look at [JSFiddle exaple](http://jsfiddle.net/d_enver/rzq2unqb/)

Comment: Mmmm, not exactly what I wanted.
I want the input to show a french format and provide to Angular an iso date if that's what it needs.