# angularjs filter and localization

Tags: angularjs, internationalization

I work on an application that should be translated in some language.

When i used filter like number, currency... the result is show in the default localization.

In the documentation i found that we can import a js to set the localization display of our application.

```
<html ng-app>
 <head>
….
   <script src="angular.js"></script>
   <script src="i18n/angular-locale_de-de.js"></script>
….
 </head>
</html>
```

What i want to do is allow the user to define his localization and in that case i think i have to change the localization script imported.

Is there a good way to do this ?

Thanks by advance for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate). Link the script file in your html and import the module in angular:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['pascalprecht.translate']);
```

Translate your texts like this:

```
<ANY>{{'TRANSLATION_ID' | translate}}</ANY>
```

And set your preferred language

```
app.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
  $translateProvider
    .translations('en', translations)
    .preferredLanguage('en');
}]);
```

You can also use `$translateProvider.determinePreferredLanguage();`to determine the user language automatically.
If you want to use different json files for each locale use [asynchronous loading](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/12_asynchronous-loading).

EDIT:
Switch your locale at runtime by

```
app.controller('Ctrl', ['$translate', '$scope', function ($translate, $scope) {

  $scope.changeLanguage = function (langKey) {
    $translate.use(langKey);
  };
}]);
```

Comment: ok thanks, i already use angular-translate. It's reply to my need for all the text element in my application but not for the date and the number format. i don't found a reply in angular-translate to manage it but maybe i miss something.

Comment: Did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937780/angularjs-translate-format-dynamic-dates) for the dates?

Comment: or if you want to use the locale scripts try [angular-dynamic-locale](https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale).

Comment: yes thanks it's seems reply to my need.
The way to manage local script is interesting with angular-dynamic-locale.
Thanks again for your reply.